John Deere D110 won't turn over
I mowed a few weeks ago and the mower started and worked fine. Went out the other day to more and it won't start. The lights come on when turn the key but that's it, nothing else happens, no sounds. Battery has 10.3v. Checked the seat switch and it works(on until depressed). Thoughts?

I guess I thought that it was so obvious there must be something else going on.

10.3 is close to a dead battery.
Charge the battery and see if it will go pass 12.4volts.
If not, get a new battery.
If it charges up to 12.4 or better, you need to check for a drain/short and see if the alternator is charging.  A good alternator should put out between 13 to 14 volts to the battery.
Maybe you just left the key on run.  It happens.

Check the battery voltage under load (when you turn the key)
The battery should be holding 12 Volt.
The charge should deliver 14.5 volt while charging.
However you might have other problem.
